# PostgreSQL: Select first row as column inside select

Tags: postgresql

I got 2 tables like `Customers` and `Orders`, in table `Customers` I got columns `id`, `name`, in table `Orders` I got columns `id`, `customer_id`, `order_date`.

Now I need to make one select that will return me each Customer's `id`, `name` and the last `order_date`.

I tried to make like this:

```
select
    Customers.id,
    Customers.name,
    (select Orders.order_date from Orders where Orders.customer_id = Customer.id order by order_date desc) as last_order_date
from
    Customers
```

But it get the wrong index and takes forever to execute.
Whats the best way to make this select in PostgreSQL?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Could you state what the index is on that it's using and what index you wish it to user as well as how many rows are in the table.

Comment: I got 2 index, one on order_date and the other is on order_date, customer_id. If I drop the first index the query is very fast, but I need that index for others queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not restricting by `customer_id`, then the query will end up having to scan the entire orders table.

```
SELECT c.id
      ,c.name
      ,MAX(o.order_date) AS last_order_date
FROM Customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o ON (o.customer_id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Comment: The problem is that this way will only return the customers that got orders, and I need all customers

Comment: Added an outer join. But look at Tim's answer and apply an outer join there if you have an index on the Orders table on order_date and customer_id and this isn't picking it up.

Comment: Hopefully he will add it back. Sub-querying on Orders[customer_id, MAX(order_id)] (or doing it in a CTE like Tim showed), would result in a full index scan rather than a full table scan. Then you can query Customers and outer join to the result from the orders.